# Printing value of multiple variable expression in Windows Batch Files

Tags: windows, batch-file, echo

So I'm trying to print out the value of a variable in the form of (variable.variable). I can't figure out how to do it. The closest thing I got was:

```
echo %"%Dog.Index%"%
```

Which just printed out:

```
Dog.Index
```

And then I tried to add another set of % tags and that printed out:

```
%""%
```

Any help would be great! Thanks.

(EDITED)

I'm trying to basically make an array-like variable. So I want the value of Dog.1, Dog.2, Dog.3 printed out and assign them as such:

```
set Dog.%index%=(Value)
```

And %index% is just a counter that I increment.
Trying "%Dog.index%" does not work, neither does %Dog%.%index%
Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll probably have to use delayed expansion of environment variables. The command `SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion` initialises the mode, after which you can use the delayed expansion by enclosing variables in `!` instead of `%`.

Here's an illustration of how it can be used:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

ECHO Initialising...
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,5) DO SET Dog.%%i=!RANDOM!

ECHO Displaying...
FOR /L %%i IN (1,1,5) DO ECHO %%i: !Dog.%%i!

SET index=3
ECHO Dog.%index% is !Dog.%index%!
```

Output:

```
Initialising...
Displaying...
1: 1443
2: 6940
3: 24198
4: 8054
5: 14092
Dog.3 is 24198
```

You can see that the last part of the script employs both the immediate and the delayed expansion. The immediate expansion replaces `%index%` with `3` and results in the variable name of `Dog.3`. Then the delayed expansion replaces the `!Dog.3!` expression with the value of the `Dog.3` variable.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! Thank you so much! It was starting to drive me a little crazy haha

Comment: +1 Nice! I wasn't familiar with the `!` alternative and delayed expansion.

Answer (score 1):

```
set Dog=(Lassie WonderPup Fido Beethoven)
for %%i in %Dog% do echo %%i
pause
```

Comment: Hi kmb385, 
Yeah that's a little different than what I'm trying to do. What I need is strange. I edited my post if that helps clear up anything. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @mike i update my post, but i just saw Ken White's and i believe his post captures what your after better than mine.  Hopefully this resolves your issues.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something like this (in a batch/cmd file - note this requires at least XP, IIRC, and command extensions have to be enabled):

```
for /l %%i in (1, 1, 10) do set Dog%%i=%%i
for /l %%j in (10, -1, 1) do echo Dog%%j is %%%Dog%%j
```

(Note that the character following `/` is a lower-case L.)

For more info on `for` (pun intended), see [MSDN TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754900%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Tested on Win7, BTW. Your mileage may vary. :)